# Complete the following proof that $-u$ is the unique vector in V such that $u+(-u)=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

suppose that $w$ satisfies $u+w=0$. Adding $-u$ to both sides we have

$(-u)+[u+w]=(-u)+0$

$[(-u)+u]+w=(-u)+0$

$0+w=(-u)+0$

$w=-u$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now suppose that $u + x = 0$ for some $x$ in $V$.  Then:

$-u = -u + 0 = -u + (u + x) = (-u + u) + x = 0 + x = x$.

Comment: Just re-read your original post and realize that I'm not quite sure what your question is. You've essentially shown that $-u$ is the unique solution (and I've only given a slightly different take).  By definition, $-u$ is a solution to the equation, and you showed that it's the only one.

Comment: See, thats where I'm confused, but thats how the question reads, verbatim, from the book, I too am confused as to what they want me to show. edit: Thanks for the answer!